# Python NGROUPS_MAX staying at 16 for Solaris

Tags: python, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to increase the amount of groups Python allows for its processes.  I have applied Solaris' 144501 patch to the operating system for it to allow more users, and after running `getconf NGROUPS_MAX` it returns `1024`.

Unfortunately, Python is still using the Solaris default `os.NGROUPS_MAX` value of `16`.

I've tried compiling Python myself, and the value continues to be `16`.  I even tried to hard code a `1024` in the source but it remains `16` after that as well.

Does anyone know how to get Python to recognize the new group limit?

Comment: doesn't `os.NGROUPS_MAX = 1024` help?

Comment: maybe you can compile it with alternative '-D-DNGROUPS_MAX=X'

Comment: Nope, still complains that there are too many groups when using `os.setgroups()`

Comment: I'm going to try that now, thkang

Comment: -DNGROUPS_MAX=1024 did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the setting was changed in the operating system, a header file still contained `16`.  In `/usr/include/limits.h`:

```
#define NGROUPS_MAX 16  /* max number of groups for a user */
```

Change that to `1024` (assuming you did the patch and `getconf NGROUPS_MAX` is 1024), everything compiles correctly after that.